# How to display a standard SharePoint "Access Denied" message

Tags: c#, sharepoint, exception

How can I re-direct the user to the standard SharePoint "access denied" page, similar to the image below?

Currently, I am throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException, but this error message is not as elegant as SP message.

```
throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("User does not have permission to access this list");
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean the method is "missing" from the assembly.  Are you missing a reference somewhere?

Comment: OK my bad. I was trying to reference: Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SendAccessDeniedHeader instead of Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.SendAccessDeniedHeader( Anyway, the SendAccessDeniedHeader only displays "401 UNAUTHORIZED" message :-/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied to do this. (You can pass in null for the exception parameter if you just want to force the Access Denied page to be displayed, but aren't actually handling an exception.)

Comment: In SP2013, passing null to HandleAccessDenied results in a NullReferenceException in the log and an error page for the user. Passing an SPException with a message results in that message showing in the log: "Access Denied. Exception: MESSAGE, StackTrace:  ..." and the "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you" page showing for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for, but if you throw an [SPException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spexception.aspx) you have greater control over the contents of the error page.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, you should be able to do this by configuring the permissions on your site correctly. If you have a page that you don't want certain users to be able to view, that page's permissions should be set up accordingly.

If this is something you're trying to do in code from some sort of event handler or another, though, you may need a different solution. There may be a specific SharePoint exception for this, but I don't know what it is off-hand.

I guess the real question is, what exactly are you trying to do that you want to block access to?